# Ngx-Translate value from global variable

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I'm new to ngx-translate and I'm trying to translate some value that goes in a dropdown component by Input, something like this:

**HTML**

```
 <dropdown [list]="someList"></dropdown>
```

**TS**

```
someList = 
[
   {code: 1, color:"red"},
   {code: 2, color:"blue"},
   {code: 3, color:"green"},
]

constructor(private translation: translateService){}
```

so I tried, in the parent component:

```
ngOnInit(){
   this.translation.instant(this.someList);
   ...
}
```

and

```
  ngOnInit(){
       this.translation.get(this.someList).subscribe(response => this.someList = response);
       ...
    }
```

but got no sucess and no error.
should I use translate in the dropdown menu?

I rather not because I have the dropdown menu in the entire application so I would have to translate it everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just refer you to the official docs as those have explained in detail how to set this up and get it running.

https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#4-define-the-translations

What it basically boils down to is that you're trying to pass your object array as the key to the `instant` method when it fact it expects a single string or an array of strings (the exact key/keys for your translation - see [docs for methods](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#methods)).

Answer (score 0):

You can structure your translation files like this:

```
{
  "someList": {
  "key1": "value1",
  "key1": "value2",
  "key1": "value",
  }
}
```

In the HTML files you can insert it like this:

```js
 <select>
        <option *ngFor="let item of someList" [value]="item">
           {{ 'someList.' + item | translate }}
        </option>        
</select>
```

Your ts file will have a variable like this:

```
someList: string[] = ['key1','key2','key3']
```